# AVCaptureSession startRunning is unmuting device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, avcapturesession

My application has various sound effects for buttons and other actions, if the device is muted/silenced they don't make sounds as expected. However, one of the screens does video recording, and if that screen is navigated to it enables all of the sound effects everywhere in the app. By commenting out some things I determined that it was the startRunning function that does this - I'm not sure if this is just normal behavior because starting the camera enables related things, like audio, or if there's something weird going on that I can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing video recording you're most likely using the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category. This category will always ignore the mute switch on the side of the device, by design. [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories) for definitions of all AVAudioSession categories. In short, there's no way to respect the mute switch when using this audio category. So maybe when you switch away from that screen, you should set the audio session category to something else like `AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient` if that will not affect your app.